# Compare two tables and return rows with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two identical tables mostly data will be same

```
Table 1
-------------------------------
     C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
R1   1     2     3     4     5
R2   6     7     8     9     10

Table 2
-------------------------------
     C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
R1   1     2     3     4     5
R2   6     17    18    9     10
R3   11    12    13    14    15
R4   16    17    18    19    20
```

Can somebody help me in writing query to compare two tables, get R3, R4 in the result set and also grab the rows which has difference in column values like C2R2, C3R2

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There are a lot of people who will be glad to help you. What have you tried so far yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first column (the one with values `R1`, `R2`, etc.) is named `row` (you don't say):

```
select row, 'Not present in table 2' as difference
from table_1
where row not in (select row from table_2)
union all
select row, 'Not present in table 1'
from table_2
where row not in (select row from table_1)
union all
select
  t1.row,
  concat(
    case when t1.c1 <> t2.c1 then 'c1 ' end,
    case when t1.c2 <> t2.c2 then 'c2 ' end,
    case when t1.c3 <> t2.c3 then 'c3 ' end,
    case when t1.c4 <> t2.c4 then 'c4 ' end,
    case when t1.c5 <> t2.c5 then 'c5 ' end
  )
from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.row = t2.row
where t1.c1 <> t2.c1
   or t1.c2 <> t2.c2
   or t1.c3 <> t2.c3
   or t1.c4 <> t2.c4
   or t1.c5 <> t2.c5
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland In the second case, I think an `INNER JOIN` is required, since it's comparing **matching** rows (I may have understood it the wrong way).

Comment: yea you right i misunderstood the question not you it seams.. never mind mine comment i will remove it.

Comment: I need only one query which does both tasks.

Comment: Queries combined into a single one.